# Magento2: Invalid template file Magento_Review::anchor.phtml

Tags: magento2

I have a live Magento 2 website working fine

I needed to make a test version of my server that running Magento

I did copy the same files and database and everything working fine except product page I get this error :

> Invalid template file: 'Magento_Review::product/view/anchor.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'product.review.anchor'

although it is the same code on the test Magento server and production Magento server but this error only on the test Magento

error from file from in theme in

> app/design/frontend/ET/base_lite/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

this is the code of this file that occur the error

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.review.anchor" template="Magento_Review::anchor.phtml" before="product.info.details" />
```

exactly from this part

```
template="Magento_Review::anchor.phtml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below information will help you.

The anchor.phtml file is not a default Magento file. It appears to be a customized file within your third-party theme.

You mentioned that the anchor.phtml file is called from the following file, which is from the third-party theme:

```
app/design/frontend/ET/base_lite/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

I recommend checking your third-party theme on the production server to see if the same file exists there. It's possible that the file was not copied from production to the test instance.

If the file does not exist on the production server, then check the production logs. The same error should be logged in the log file.

Comment: indeed the same error exist in production logs. I ended up with removing the line as it does not effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the original phtml file, because as I checked I haven't found anchor.phtml in my vendor/ folder, so I guess you're trying to override the file of vendor/ which is not available in the vendor/ folder